# Ignore automatically generated tabindex's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabindex, jqxgrid

I have a form that uses `tabindex` to logically traverse through the input fields in the form. However, within my form there is a [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28web%29) grid that also applies `tabindex` to its elements. As my input fields are nested within `div`'s, the tabindex order is being messed up so instead of traversing in the correct order, when using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button, the focus jumps about the page.

Can anybody see of a way, either using HTML or Javascript (jQuery), to prevent this from occuring?

I have tried nesting the grid further down the DOM but this had no affect...

***The structure of the HTML must remain the same for all of the `input` fields***

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/TN7xL/1/

Or alternatively, here is a sample of my code (*I have stripped out all irrelevant id's and classes*):

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div>
                <label for="foo">Foo</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" tabindex="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="bar">Bar</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="bar" name="bar" tabindex="2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" tabindex="3" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" tabindex="4" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- THERE ARE MORE ROWS AND COLUMNS IN MY FULL SCRIPT -->
    <div id="grid" class="row">
        <!-- THE FOLLOWING IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY JQWIDGETS -->
        <div tabindex="0">
            <div tabindex="1">GRID HERE</div>
        </div>
        <!-- THE ABOVE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY JQWIDGETS -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div>
                <label for="field">Another Field</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="field" name="field" tabindex="5" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My aim is to effectively ignore the `tabindex`'s that are set by the jQWidgets grid, but I cannot see a way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this, it is clear that the only solution is to get rid of the `tabindex`'s on any elements within the grid. I therefore implemented the following code to select any element within the grid (when it is initiated) that has a `tabindex` set, and then I remove it.

```
ready: function(){
    // Remove any tabindex's set by the grid
    $('#grid [tabindex]').removeAttr('tabindex');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you don't know what jqWidget tabindex is set, I use this strategy:
1- I give my tabindex order to every input that I introduce,
2- I give them a "tabindex" class,
3- I remove every tabindex that is not what I have introduced after every jqWidget initialization.

```
<html>
    <input type="text" class="tabindex" tabindex="2" />
    <div id="split"> ... </div>

<script>
    $("#split").jqxSplitter(settings);

    // Delete every tabindex introduced by jqWidgets
    $("[tabindex]:not(.tabindex)").removeProp("tabindex").removeAttr("tabindex");
```

This solution works pretty well with almost every jqWidget component.
In grid or in every loop situation you can use knockout with data-bind "attr: {class 'tabindex', tabindex: $index}"

Known Bug:
If you have a Navigation Bar, tab jumps from it to address bar.


my 2 cents

N

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the auto-generated tabindex by using the jQuery's removeAttr method. http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: It is not as simple as that! There is no telling which elements within the grid have been set a `tabindex`, and I am not too keen on altering the code generated by jQWidgets as I do not want to break any of the functions within the grid...

Comment: The "tabindex" is something which is usually useful for keyboard navigation in DIV tags as otherwise they will not handle key events in some browsers like FF. I suppose that it the reason of those "tabindex" attributes. If you know exactly which elements have "tabindex" attribute, remove those and you may then add/remove the attributes on events like "mouseenter", "mouseleave". That should not break the Grid's functionality.

Comment: I am well aware what the `tabindex` is for, my issue is removing it from the elements within the grid... How can I select all elements within the grid that have a `tabindex` set!!??

Answer (score -1):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').removeAttr("tabindex");
});`